# How to go back to old activity with sending information

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

I have a main Activity which starts an other activity and then, the main activity should receive information from the last activity. But when I finish the latest activity I come to the second, not to the mainActivity of course. How do I get there without starting a new one?
Thanks a lot, Vinzenz :)

Here's a part of it: (editet)

I am sorry, but I don't get it.
In my MainActivity I start the second one with:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, currentxyzIndex);         
}
```

In the second Activity I start an other one with:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 100); 
    finish();           
}
```

and in this one I want to return to the first one:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    int xyzIndex = position;

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);

    in.putExtra("xyzIndex", xyzIndex);
    setResult(100, in);

    finish();
}
```

Comment: you can call finish in the second Activity,

Comment: but then I cant start this one cause it closes everytime i want to open it ?

Comment: `finish()` will close the activity that you're calling from. Your question is really hard to follow; please edit your question and state explicitly how many activities you have (e.g. Activity A, Activity B, Activity C), and give the desired flow (e.g. app opens at Activity A, then I click a button and it should open Activity B, then another button clicked in B, and B should close, and return to A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should start the `SecondActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` and override in the MainAcitvity `onActivityResult()`. This way, when you call finish() on the SecondActivity, `onActivityResult()` of the MainActivity is called. The signature of onActivityResult is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data)
```

if before `finish()` on your SecontActivity, you call `setResult(int, Intent)`, the last one will be the parameter data of `onActivityResult`

Comment: I am sorry.But I dont get it running.Maybe you want to read my editet quistion and help me again.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about startActvityForResult and onActivityForResult ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question now but you should edit it to make it clearer. I will summarise what I think you're trying to do.

There are three activities: A, B and C.

In Activity A, you have some button or view which, when clicked, will open Activity B with `startActivityForResult()`.

In Activity B, you have some button or view which, when clicked, will open Activity C with `startActivityForResult()`.

In Activity C, you set some data, set the result, and call finish, hoping to return to Activity A.

---

As blackbelt has stated, you should use `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` in your activities. This should be in every activity that uses `startActivityForResult()` namely, Activity A and Activity B.

Activity A:

```
onClick() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class), currentxyzIndex);
}

@Override
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // this is the data that comes back from Activity B when Activity B calls finish()
    // do as you need
}
```

Activity B:

```
onClick() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class), 100);
    // do not call finish here! 
}

@Override
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // this is the data that comes back from Activity C when Activity C calls finish()

    // set the data as the result
    setResult(...);

    // then you can finish
    finish();
}
```

Activity C is as you do, I believe.

It smells fishy that your app architecture requires you to do this; perhaps if you describe your issue with information about the domain and what the purpose of each Activity is (what each represents for the user), it could be reformulated.